# Summing values from different dictionaries in a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, sum

So, I'm trying to write a code to do the following things:

1. Add, into a list, multiple lists. (with protein sequences; AKA amino acids)
2. Count how many of each amino acid (str) there are, per sequence (list).
3. Create a dictionary to associate each key (amino acid) to a specific value (molecular weight)
4. Get the total molecular weight (multiplying the number of each amino acid per its associated value)
5. Sum the total value of each protein sequence (list).

The problem is; I can get the sum of each dictionary but I cannot sum the final values of those dictionaries. Do you know any way of solving this problem?

```
    # Add different list of protein sequences (proteinx) into a list of lists (proteins)
    proteins=[]

    protein1= ['ALA', 'VAL', 'GLY', 'GLU', 'ALA', 'ALA', 'GLY', 'PHE', 'VAL', 'TYR', 'THR', 'Y', 'A', 'W']

    protein2= ['MET', 'K', 'F', 'G', 'N', 'F', 'L', 'LEU', 'T', 'Y', 'Q', 'P', 'P', 'E', 'L', 'SER', 'Q', 'T', 'A','W','CYS','C']

    # Add different list of protein sequences (proteinx) into a list of lists (proteins)
    proteins.append(protein1)
    proteins.append(protein2)

    # Count how many amino acids there are in each list (protein sequence)

    for protein in proteins:
        CAla=(protein.count('A') + protein.count('ALA'))
        CArg=(protein.count('R') + protein.count('ARG'))
        CAsn=(protein.count('N') + protein.count('ASN'))
        CAsp=(protein.count('D') + protein.count('ASP'))
        CCys=(protein.count('C') + protein.count('CYS'))
        CGln=(protein.count('Q') + protein.count('GLN'))
        CGlu=(protein.count('E') + protein.count('GLU'))
        CGly=(protein.count('G') + protein.count('GLY'))
        CHis=(protein.count('H') + protein.count('HIS'))
        CIle=(protein.count('I') + protein.count('ILE'))
        CLeu=(protein.count('L') + protein.count('LEU'))
        CLys=(protein.count('K') + protein.count('LYS'))
        CMet=(protein.count('M') + protein.count('MET'))
        CPhe=(protein.count('F') + protein.count('PHE'))
        CPro=(protein.count('P') + protein.count('PRO'))
        CSer=(protein.count('S') + protein.count('SER'))
        CThr=(protein.count('T') + protein.count('THR'))
        CTrp=(protein.count('W') + protein.count('TRP'))
        CTyr=(protein.count('Y') + protein.count('TYR'))
        CVal=(protein.count('V') + protein.count('VAL'))

      #Create a dictionary to associate each amino acid to its molecular weight and the number of each amino acid
      AAmolma = {'Ala': [CAla * (89)], 'Arg': [CArg * (174)], 'Asn': [CAsn * (132)],
           'Asp': [CAsp * (133)], 'Cys': [CCys * (121)], 'Gln': [CGln * (146)], 'Glu': [CGlu * (147)],
           'His': [CHis * (155)], 'Ile': [CIle * (131)], 'Leu': [CLeu * (131)], 'Lys': [CLys * (146)],
           'Met': [CMet * (149)], 'Phe': [CPhe * (165)], 'Pro': [CPro * (115)], 'Ser': [CSer * (105)],
           'Thr': [CThr * (119)], 'Trp': [CTrp * (204)], 'Tyr': [CTyr * (181)], 'Val': [CVal * (117)], 
           'Gly': [CGly * (75)]}

      #sum all the values in each dictionary and then the total value of each dictionary
        parmw=0
        for mw in AAmolma.values():
            parmw+=sum(mw)
        print(parmw)

     totmw=0
     for i in parmw:
         totmw+=sum(parmw)
```

What I get is:

```
1737
2953
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-43b4557ce807> in <module>
     38 
     39 totmw=0
---> 40 for i in parmw:
     41     totmw+=sum(parmw)
     42 

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

In this particular example all I want to do is sum 1737 + 2953 to get 4690

## Thank you!! hope someone can help!!

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to `.append` to a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not quite following the instructions that you provided. For step #3 you should "Create a dictionary to associate each key (amino acid) to a specific value (molecular weight)"  That dictionary would just look like:

```
AAmolma = {'Ala': 89, 'Arg': 174, .....
```

You multiplied the count and put that into the dictionary. That defeats the point of ever using a dictionary. You also created a list when you put in the value with `[CAla * (89)]`, but there was no need for a list here. It is a one entry list that would always be a one entry list. That is why you needed to use `sum(mw)` later to get the value instead of just `mw`.

Next problem is that you accumulated into your counters such as `CAla` the count for all the list combined. You are supposed to be counting for each sequence independently.

In the end you are supposed to "Sum the total value of each protein sequence (list).", so for your example there should just be two answers since you have two sequences.

If you move the dictionary definition up, then you can change the for loop to look something like

```
   for protein in proteins:
    total = (
      (protein.count('A') + protein.count('ALA')) * AAmolma['Ala'] +
      (protein.count('R') + protein.count('ARG')) * AAmolma['Arg'] +
      ....
    )
    print(total)
```

I would also want to make the items that are being counted into some constant list or tuple like `(('A', 'ALA', 'Ala'), ('R', 'ARG', 'Arg'), ..` and iterate through them instead of all this duplicated code, but you can do that as a second step.

Comment: This is actually very very helpful and valuable! Thank you very much for the contribution I did it this way and it works perfectly!
I also think that having a list to recognize variables of the same value can be very useful, but not quite sure how to do it. If you can prove some info about it it will be amazing! thanks!

Comment: @EdwinOA I'm not sure that I understand your question.  Are you referring to the last part that I said that you could do as a second step, or are you interested in something else?

Comment: Ah alright, then I perhaps didn't get right the second part but yeah, I am actually referring to the last part that can be done as a second step.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to iterate through an integer (note that an error would also be raised on line 41 because of `sum(parmw)`
One solution would be to put `totmw = 0` outside the for loop and then `totmw += parmw` after you're done calculating parmw.